# flutter, adding a PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to modify my Navigation Transition code to use PageRouteBuilder. See method _gotoThirdPage().
The problem is that I cannot pass parameters to new Page. For example, I crash when passing title.  Also looking for examples of sending multiple parameters, such as a map.
REQUEST:  Could someone Modify the _gotoThirdPage() method to send parameters to Class SecondPage.
//====================. Code below ===================

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),

    // Added  ===
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
       SecondPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new SecondPage(title: "SecondPage"),
     },


    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _gotoSecondPage,
              child: new Text("Goto SecondPage- Normal"),
            ),

            new RaisedButton(onPressed: _gotoThirdPage,
            child: new Text("goto SecondPage = with PRB"),
            ),

            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _gotoSecondPage() {
    //=========================================================
    //  Transition - Normal Platform Specific
    print('====  going to second page ===');
    print( SecondPage.routeName);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, SecondPage.routeName);
  }

  void _gotoThirdPage() {
    //=========================================================
    //  I believe this is where I would be adding a PageRouteBuilder
    print('====  going to second page ===');
    print( SecondPage.routeName);
    //Navigator.pushNamed(context, SecondPage.routeName);

    //=========================================================
    //===  please put PageRouteBuilderCode here.

    final pageRoute = new PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        // YOUR WIDGET CODE HERE
        //  I need to PASS title here...
        // not sure how to do this.
        // Also, is there a way to clean this code up?


      return new SecondPage();
      },
      transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: new Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: new SlideTransition(
            position: new Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset.zero,
              end: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
            ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(pageRoute);



  }
}


class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = "/SecondPage";

  final String title;

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => new _SecondPageState();
}

/// // 1. After the page has been created, register it with the app routes 
/// routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
///   SecondPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new SecondPage(title: "SecondPage"),
/// },
///
/// // 2. Then this could be used to navigate to the page.
/// Navigator.pushNamed(context, SecondPage.routeName);
///

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        //========   HOW TO PASS widget.title ===========
        title: new Text(widget.title),
        //title: new Text('====  second page ==='),
      ),
      body: new Container(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _onFloatingActionButtonPressed,
        tooltip: 'Add',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onFloatingActionButtonPressed() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. The easiest way to *pass parameters to new Page* for me is using the constructor of the new page if I need to do some processing- show/ use/ pass them later on. Although I dont think it is appropriate if you have large number of parameters.

So in some cases I would use [SharedPrefences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences). I think this will be better for *sending multiple parameters, such as a map*.

Btw about your navigation I advise you to use Navigate with named routes. Something like:

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In our case, the app will start
  // on the FirstScreen Widget
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When we navigate to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen Widget
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When we navigate to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen Widget
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

And then:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
```

[Documentation](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/named-routes/).

Comment: I am using your solution with the _gotoSecondPage.  using a named route.  But I chage the navigation transition happens.  instead of the standard Android way of transitioning bottom to top, I want to force all transitions to go Right to left... as if it were a UINavigationController.    So I added code... void _gotoThirdPage(), where I am able to transition RtoL... but I cannot figure out how to pass parameters.

Comment: I reposted the question in simpler terms... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175916/flutter-passing-parameters-to-pageroutebuilder